# how to create custom pop up in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am newbie to Xamarin.Forms and stuck with a situation where I want to Create up a popup box with my control details.

How can I open and create custom dialog box / popup using Xamarin.Forms?

Any example code will be appreciated?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Using Alessandro Caliaro answer below is how we have done all of the popups in our app. If you get stuck or need some examples let me know.

Answer (score 3):

What I have used is a StackLayout(or any layout) within a grid (or even an absolute layout ) this main grid will have 2 children. The IsVisible property of the popup layout will be set to false and when it is needed then the IsVisible property will be set to true and it will appear, something like this:

```
Grid mainGrid = new Grid{};
mainGrid.Children.Add(mainLayout,0,0); 
mainGrid.Children.Add(popUpLayout,0,0);

Content = mainGrid;
```

if what you want is different then a custom renderer will be the way. Here are some helpful links:

http://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2013/02/using-dialogs-in-mono-for-android.html

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/30456/xamarin-forms-control-into-a-native-custom-dialog-android

There are different kind of things to achieve this, but I will say play with the layouts because it will work for all 3 platforms.

The Frame will be useful also:
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Frame/